# How to auto-rotate a MeshRegion?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, mesh, image3d, 3d-printing

I have a 3D MeshRegion `region1` as below:

```
region1 = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 
2}}, {Tetrahedron[{1, 2, 3, 5}], Tetrahedron[{1, 3, 4, 5}]}]
```

I want to display `region1` in a way that it will rotate automatically. What are the good ways to do so?

many thanks!

Comment: I am not clear as to what you mean by automatically.  `Manipulate[
 TransformedRegion[region1, 
  RotationTransform[theta, {1, 1, 1}]], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]` will rotate your shape about the `{1,1,1}` axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Animate:

```
Animate[With[{v = RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}][{4, 0, 1}]}, 
  Show[{region1}, SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> v, 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Using Dynamic:

```
Dynamic[Show[{region1}, 
  ViewPoint -> 
   RotationTransform[Clock[{0, 2 Pi}, 10], {0, 0, 1}][{4, 0, 1}], 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}, SphericalRegion -> True]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Which of them requires lower computational cost?

Comment: maybe the second one, but you can't stop it though..